# Creating a function that returns a new identical binary tree and adds new nodes to all pre-existing leaves

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

Create a function that returns a new binary tree identical to the binary tree passed in except that every leaf in the new tree now has a left child and a right child whose values are equal to x and y.

Comment: I think that this is one of the situations where you will benefit a lot [if you were to explain this code your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). There are some obvious logical flaws in this code, that your rubber duck should be able to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. The case that handles the expansion is correct, but you messed up the iteration a bit. Here's a possible solution:

```
void expand_leaf(TreeNode * node, int x, int y)
{
    // recursively iterate over tree:
    if (node->left)  expand_leaf(node->left, x, y);
    if (node->right) expand_leaf(node->right, x, y);

    // expand leafes:
    if (!node->left && !node->right)
    {
        node->left  = new TreeNode(x, nullptr, nullptr);
        node->right = new TreeNode(y, nullptr, nullptr);
    }
}
```

Your problem can be elegantly decomposed into two sub-problems:

1. Find all leafs in the tree.
2. Add children x and y to leafs.

One viable way to find all leafs, is to iterate over ALL nodes of the tree and check if they are leafs (if their left/right pointers are null). This is what the first part of the above expand_leaf function does: Whenever a child pointer is present, it is recursively visited. This effectively visits all nodes of the entire tree.

Now that we have a means to visit all nodes, we can filter out the leafs. This is what the second part of the function does. Whenever we discover a leaf, we add the x/y children to it.

It is very important that the expansion happens after the recursive call. Otherwise we would end up in an infinite loop. Consider why.

#### Comments on original solution

The abort condition/base case is needed and mostly correct, but you create a new TreeNode prematurely. If you then discover that node==null, you overwrite the just-created n with null also, which results in a memory leak. Solution: Simplify the base case to `if (node == nullptr) return nullptr;` and move `TreeNode * n = new TreeNode;` past the if, once you know that you aren't dealing with a null node.

The rest looks functionally correct (haven't run the code). Perhaps it can be improved further for readability?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (node->left != nullptr) expand_leaf(....)`? And shouldn't you make the new TreeNodes have there left and right pointer point to nullptr? Also the function shouldn't be `void`, it should return a new TreeNode.

Comment: Wouldn't it recurse infinitely if it doesn't stop at null nodes? Isn't this `if (node== NULL) return node;` still required at the top of the recursive function?

Comment: new TreeNode(x, nullptr, nullptr) is meant to make left/right point to nullptr. It's a short-form notation of your original code. expand_leaf expands ALL leafs of the entire tree. Which of those TreeNodes should it return?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 The function terminates because it reaches a leaf eventually, which neither has a left, nor a right sub tree. Thus, no recursive call occurs. All paths from the root end in leafs. QED.

Comment: @denniskb Ah, I see it now, your code is just so simple - which is good of course.

Comment: But wouldn't it be good to have a null check just in case the value passed in is null?

Comment: @denniskb How would I go about "fixing" the one I wrote above? Trying to get an idea as to where I messed up. Thank you.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I agree. I was just trying to illustrate concepts. Obviously my code isn't battle-hardened ;)

Comment: @StacksAndParsing I updated my answer with a more detailed analysis of your solution which should help you transform it into a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

```
# define KEY(p) (p->data)
# define LLINK(p) (p->left)
# define RLINK(p) (p->right)

TreeNode * expand_leaf(TreeNode * node, int x, int y)
{
  if (node == nullptr) 
    return nullptr; // copy of empty tree is an empty tree

  TreeNode * root = new TreeNode(KEY(node)); // node copy with its key

  if (LLINK(node) == nullptr and RLINK(node)) // node is leaf? (this is the base case)
    {    // yes ==> create children with x and y
      LLINK(root) = new TreeNode(x);
      RLINK(root) = new TreeNode(y);
      return root;
    }

  LLINK(root) = expand_leaf(LLINK(node), x, y); 
  RLINK(root) = expand_leaf(RLINK(node), x, y);

  return root;
}
```

For simplicity, I assume a constructor for `TreeNode` class which receives the key. If you have not it, then you could add an additional line for setting the key value